# Database changes management in installer updates

Tags: sql, wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

How can I run a series of database scripts depending on some condition?

Basically I want to check build installed on user's machine and then want to run all the scripts till the build in the installer.

Say user has build number 4.10 installed and if he goes to install build 4.15 then I want to run SQL scripts of builds 4.111 to 4.15.

I'm trying this but it says condition element can't be nested in SQL script element.

```
<sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV11" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV11"  ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="11">
             <Condition>INSTALLED_BUILD < 4.11 </Condition>
 </sql:SqlScript>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Note: INSTALLED_BUILD property is set using registry search.

Comment: may be i should make each builds script as separate component ?

Comment: Run scripts like this from your applications startup routine and not in the setup itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions can be applied to Components, but a gotcha using multiple components is you can't rely on the components being installed in any particular order.  However you can control the sequencing of scripts.  See this related question: [Can I ensure components installation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252880/).

With this in mind, and you really want to do the upgrade in the installer, you could try something like:

```
<Component Id="UpgradeFromV410" Guid="--Your GUID--">
    <Condition>INSTALLED AND (INSTALLED_BUILD=4.10)</Condition>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV10V11" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV11" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="11"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV10V12" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV12" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="12"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV10V13" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV13" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="13"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV10V14" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV14" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="14"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV10V15" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV15" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="15"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="UpgradeFromV411" Guid="--Your GUID--">
    <Condition>INSTALLED AND (INSTALLED_BUILD=4.11)</Condition>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV11V12" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV12" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="12"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV11V13" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV13" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="13"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV11V14" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV14" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="14"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV11V15" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV15" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="15"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="UpgradeFromV412" Guid="--Your GUID--">
    <Condition>INSTALLED AND (INSTALLED_BUILD=4.12)</Condition>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV12V13" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV13" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="13"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV12V14" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV14" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="14"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV12V15" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV15" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="15"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="UpgradeFromV413" Guid="--Your GUID--">
    <Condition>INSTALLED AND (INSTALLED_BUILD=4.13)</Condition>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV13V14" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV14" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="14"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV13V15" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV15" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="15"/>
</Component>

<Component Id="UpgradeFromV414" Guid="--Your GUID--">
    <Condition>INSTALLED AND (INSTALLED_BUILD=4.14)</Condition>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="ScriptV13V15" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" ExecuteOnUninstall="no" BinaryKey="FileV15" ContinueOnError="no" Sequence="15"/>
</Component>
```

As a solution this is just about OK, if your releases are relatively few and far between.  If you have a frequent release schedule, this solution would quickly become un-maintainable.

@Stein's comment about running the upgrade scripts at start would offer you much more control and be easier to maintain in the long term.